# Perform two save("entity-name",object) in a single session of hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a POJO class NewUniversity.java. I've created a mapping file for it viz. RegisterAction.hbm.xml. Now the problem is when I try to call the save methods from DAO class, only the first one gets executed, the second one doesn't. I've two tables linked to one entity through 'entity-mapping' attribute in the xml file.

File: NewUniversity.java

```
public class NewUniversity implements Serializable {

// University fields
private String uCode;
private String uName;
private String uAddress;
private String uCity;
private String uState;
private long uContactNo;
private String uEmail;

// University director fields
private String name;
private String address;
private String city;
private String state;
private long contactNo;
private String email;
private String userName;
private String pwd;

public String getuCode() {
    return uCode;
}

public void setuCode(String uCode) {
    this.uCode = uCode;
}

public String getuName() {
    return uName;
}

public void setuName(String uName) {
    this.uName = uName;
}

public String getuAddress() {
    return uAddress;
}

public void setuAddress(String uAddress) {
    this.uAddress = uAddress;
}

public String getuCity() {
    return uCity;
}

public void setuCity(String uCity) {
    this.uCity = uCity;
}

public String getuState() {
    return uState;
}

public void setuState(String uState) {
    this.uState = uState;
}

public long getuContactNo() {
    return uContactNo;
}

public void setuContactNo(long uContactNo) {
    this.uContactNo = uContactNo;
}

public String getuEmail() {
    return uEmail;
}

public void setuEmail(String uEmail) {
    this.uEmail = uEmail;
}


// University directors setters/getters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public long getContactNo() {
    return contactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(long contactNo) {
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPwd() {
    return pwd;
}

public void setPwd(String pwd) {
    this.pwd = pwd;
}

}
```

File: RegisterAction.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD  3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="in.ryr.register.NewUniversity" table="university"
    entity-name="university">
    <id name="uCode" column="code" type="string">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="uName" column="name" />
    <property name="uAddress" column="address" />
    <property name="uCity" column="city" />
    <property name="uState" column="state" />
    <property name="uContactNo" column="contact_no" />
    <property name="uEmail" column="email" />
    <property name="userName" column="username" />
</class>

<class name="in.ryr.register.NewUniversity" table="university_director"
    entity-name="uniDirector">
    <id name="userName" column="username" type="string">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" />
    <property name="address" column="address" />
    <property name="city" column="city" />
    <property name="state" column="state" />
    <property name="contactNo" column="contact_no" />
    <property name="email" column="email" />
    <property name="pwd" column="password" />
    <property name="uCode" column="u_code" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

File: RegisterDAO.java

```
public void register(NewUniversity user) throws Exception {
    session = factory.openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.save("university", user);   //This is working fine
        session.save("uniDirector", user);  //This doesn't execute at all
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

I've tried using persist() as well. But no luck! 
The point is, when I perform it on two different sessions, it works perfectly. (All the objects value are coming through .jsp to struts). For some reasons I didn't use annotations.

Comment: Try `session.flush()` and `session.clear()` after saving first entity

Comment: Create a new instance of `user` object. More better is to create a separate classes for two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because [Session#save(entityName, object)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method requires `object` to be a "transient" object (i.e. that has not already been persisted), and that, after the first call to `session.save("university", user);` then `user` is no more transient.

> Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated
>   identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if
>   the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped with cascade="save-update"

What happens when you make a get of your persisted "university" entity just after the first `save`, and then save it as "uniDirector" ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jérémy. Can you please further tell me the workaround of the problem. Should I use merge() or anything else.

Comment: Also, how do I convert a persisted object to transient object.

Comment: @SuryaDeepMishra remove it from the session.